# tSQLt : How to compare result set (dynamic column return) from call stored procedure without define the structure table

Tags: sql, tsqlt

Please help me to compare the result set(dynamic columns) from caller stored procedure without define the structure table using tSQLt

SP:

```
ALTER   PROCEDURE [dbo].[spa_Test]
    @Param1 INT 
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    IF @Param1 = 1
    BEGIN
        SELECT [A] = 123 FROM Position  
    END
    ELSE IF @Param1 = 2
    BEGIN
        SELECT [A] = 321, [B] = 534 FROM Position
    END 
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT [C] = 456, [D] = 896, [E] = 434 FROM Position
    END 
END
```

Compare result for 2 result(without define structure table to catch result set), have another way without define structure before?

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE TestProcedureModification.TestCompareResult
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable 'EXEC spa_Test @Param1 = 1', 'EXEC spa_Test @Param1 = 2' --Error
END;
GO
EXEC tSQLt.RunTestClass 'TestProcedureModification.TestCompareResult'
```

Comment: Why is this all in one proc? It will be easier to unit test if each proc is doing a defined thing. And also this is not dynamic. It just has different paths. So why wouldn't your tests for `@Param1 = 2` know what the shape of the expected results for that are?

Comment: Hi Martin Smith, Thank you for the feedback, I would like using tSQLt to compare for 2 result (like using OPENROWSET to catch the result to compare result of 2 execute command) in the one spa test case of tSQLt

Comment: I can't answer your question but I do agree with the prior comment that it's a bad idea to have a stored procedure that returns dataset with different column names and counts. In fact if possible you should often use a table valued function to return rowsetss as SP's have some limitations.

Comment: Hi Nick.MC, Thank you for the feedback. I have a case to test: 1 sp with many profiler and return many column in 1 result set, i need to improve the code for this sp, and i would like to compare result between old sp with new sp(improved) based on many profiler of old sp to ensure that the improve code dose not impact existing logic of sp.

Comment: I'm using tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable but each profiler returns a different number of columns then i can not define structure table.

Comment: I can't solve your tSQLt problem. I can only reinforce that this is a bad underlying design